# Trying to get ScalaTest working: "There are no tests to run" when doing "mvn test"

Tags: scala, maven, automated-tests

Edit: I finally got it to work!!!

It needed a combination of JUnit in the pom.xml, and three statements in my .scala:

```
import org.junit.runner.RunWith
import org.scalatest.junit.JUnitRunner

@RunWith(classOf[JUnitRunner])
```

For some reason, trying to configure Surefire makes the tests stop running again.

---

I'm coding in IntelliJ, trying to get a simple ScalaTest test running via a Maven (`mvn test`) build process. There aren't any errors, but unfortunately no tests run either.

Here is my .scala file:

```
import org.scalatest.FunSuite
import org.scalatest.BeforeAndAfter

class ExampleSuite extends FunSuite with BeforeAndAfter {

  before {
    println("Doing setup tasks...")
  }

  test("Example test of checking the browser title") {

    val expected_title = "Company Platform"
    var actual_title = "Company Platform"
    assert(actual_title == expected_title)
  }

  after {
    println("Doing teardown tasks...")
  }
}
```

Here's the Maven output:

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] Some problems were encountered while building the effective model for JoeTestDemo:JoeTestDemo:jar:1.0
[WARNING] 'build.plugins.plugin.version' for org.scala-tools:maven-scala-plugin is missing. @ line 42, column 21
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] It is highly recommended to fix these problems because they threaten the stability of your build.
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] For this reason, future Maven versions might no longer support building such malformed projects.
[WARNING] 
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building JoeTestDemo 1.0
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.4.3:resources (default-resources) @ JoeTestDemo ---
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (MacRoman actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] Copying 0 resource
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:compile (default-compile) @ JoeTestDemo ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-scala-plugin:2.15.2:compile (default) @ JoeTestDemo ---
[INFO] Checking for multiple versions of scala
[INFO] includes = [**/*.scala,**/*.java,]
[INFO] excludes = []
[WARNING] No source files found.
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.4.3:testResources (default-testResources) @ JoeTestDemo ---
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (MacRoman actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory /Users/Joeshaver/Projects/JoeTestDemo/src/test/resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ JoeTestDemo ---
[INFO] No sources to compile
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-scala-plugin:2.15.2:testCompile (default) @ JoeTestDemo ---
[INFO] Checking for multiple versions of scala
[INFO] includes = [**/*.scala,**/*.java,]
[INFO] excludes = []
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.7.2:test (default-test) @ JoeTestDemo ---
[INFO] Surefire report directory: /Users/Joeshaver/Projects/JoeTestDemo/target/surefire-reports

-------------------------------------------------------
 T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------
There are no tests to run.

Results :

Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 1.368s
[INFO] Finished at: Tue Oct 23 10:58:30 PDT 2012
[INFO] Final Memory: 6M/81M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Here is the pom.xml. I think my Maven Scala plugin might not be right:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>JoeTestDemo</groupId>
    <artifactId>JoeTestDemo</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>scala-tools.org</id>
            <name>Scala-tools Maven2 Repository</name>
            <url>http://scala-tools.org/repo-releases</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>scala-tools.org</id>
            <name>Scala-tools Maven2 Repository</name>
            <url>http://scala-tools.org/repo-releases</url>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
            <artifactId>scala-library</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.0-1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.scalatest</groupId>
            <artifactId>scalatest_2.9.0-1</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.scala-tools</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-scala-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>compile</goal>
                            <goal>testCompile</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <sourceDir>src/main/java</sourceDir>
                    <jvmArgs>
                        <jvmArg>-Xms64m</jvmArg>
                        <jvmArg>-Xmx1024m</jvmArg>
                    </jvmArgs>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: You don't have to use the JUnitRunner to get it working. Use the `scalatest-maven-plugin` instead.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you're running on Maven, then you'll either have to annotate your test class(es) with

```
@RunWith(classOf[JUnitRunner])
```

This would require you having JUnit as a dependency. Or you could use the [ScalaTest Maven Plugin](http://www.scalatest.org/user_guide/using_the_scalatest_maven_plugin) (haven't used it myself though).

Comment: Blake, understood. I'd like to use the plugin, but I'm not sure how. Do I need an additional commandline switch for Maven? Or maybe just a correct pom.xml? I'll update the question with my pom.xml above.

Comment: Did you check the link? I believe it's just a matter of adding the plugin and binding it to the test phase. And be sure to add  oss.sonatype.org as a pluginRepository.

Answer (score 14):

You might want to use the [`scalatest-maven-plugin`](http://www.scalatest.org/user_guide/using_the_scalatest_maven_plugin) to run your scala tests.

Also make sure that you use the `<scope>test</scope>` for jars needed only for test purposes.

This is how I have defined my `pom.xml` for using [ScalaTest](http://www.scalatest.org/):

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.stackoverflow</groupId>
    <artifactId>Q13036561</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <name>${project.artifactId}-${project.version}</name>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <scala.version>2.9.2</scala.version>
        <scalatest.version>2.0.M4</scalatest.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
            <artifactId>scala-library</artifactId>
            <version>${scala.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.scalatest</groupId>
            <artifactId>scalatest_${scala.version}</artifactId>
            <version>${scalatest.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.scala-tools</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-scala-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.15.2</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>scala-compile</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>compile</goal>
                            <goal>testCompile</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <args>
                                <arg>-make:transitive</arg>
                                <arg>-dependencyfile</arg>
                                <arg>${project.build.directory}/.scala_dependencies</arg>
                            </args>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <!--
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.7.2</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>default-test</id>
                        < ! - Disable the default-test by putting it in phase none - >
                        <phase>none</phase>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.scalatest</groupId>
                <artifactId>scalatest-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.0-M2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <reportsDirectory>${project.build.directory}/surefire-reports</reportsDirectory>
                    <stdout>W</stdout> <!-- Skip coloring output -->
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>scala-test</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>test</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

As you can see I have also added a section that disables the surefire plugin if you really don't want to run it. It is commented in the above pom but if you want to disable the surefire plugin just uncomment that part.

I am using IntelliJ too and there are no problems at all with this combination. Just run the tests from within IntelliJ or by using `mvn test`, they will both work.

Comment: +1 for the `Skip coloring output` flag. I was searching for it!

Comment: +1 for a small little detail for being able to disable the scalatest color codes that appear when running maven through intellij's console. (I so hope google picks these keywords up! This doesn't seem to be documented anywhere else)

Comment: very concise solution @maba

Answer (score 7):

Adding to Blake's answer, besides `@RunWith(classOf[JUnitRunner])` you might also need to set the surefire as follows:

```
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.12</version>
    <configuration>
      <includes>
        <include>**/*Suite.class</include>
        <include>**/*Test.class</include>
        <include>**/*Tests.class</include>
        <include>**/*Spec.class</include>
        <include>**/*Specs.class</include>
      </includes>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
```

Here's one of my Maven projects which tests just fine by ScalaTest without any special plugin: https://github.com/nikita-volkov/sext/

Comment: I'd like to try to not use JUnit. Adding the Surefire plugin did not help.

Comment: FYI, using the JUnitRunner would also enable you to run the tests from IntelliJ.